# Ubuntu - my computer boots to a blank screen with a prompt after Updates

Tags: boot, updates

After installing updates, Ubuntu boots to a blank screen with a non-blinking underscore on the upper left (Lenovo ThinkBook).

What I've tried:

- I'm able to get into recovery mode, access root and read logs, but I'm not sure where to look to start fixing it and what might be the issue.
- I've also tried booting using a previous kernel, but the outcome is the same.
- I've tried to disable X at boot time so it boots in text mode, but with no luck.

I've added a few screenshots with everything I see until I get to the blank screen, where it freezes.

I'm not sure how to go about debugging this, can you help me?

[image: Link to first screenshot]

[image: Link to second screenshot]

[image: Link to third screenshot]

Comment: What version of Ubuntu is it and are you able to boot into a live session?

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I was able to boot a live session from a USB stick and I have Ubuntu version 22.10.

Answer (score 0):

Please try Boot-Repair as explained in the Ubuntu documentation [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair).

Comment: Thank you, it solved my problem! By using Boot-Repair I got an error with partition full. Turns out that after the updates I was left with no available space and I did not get any error for this.

Answer (score 0):

A less invasive action to take as `/boot/` is full
*(the most common cause as it seems)*...

Boot into recovery mode, then do...

```
$ dpkg --list |  grep -E "^ii.*linux-image"  # find out which ones are installed
ii  linux-image-5.13.0-52-generic                 5.13.0-52.59~20.04.1                       amd64        Signed kernel image generic

$ uname -rv                        # Check which kernel version you have running
5.13.0-52-generic #59~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jun 16 21:21:28 UTC 2022

$ sudo apt purge linux-image-OTHER-THAN-uname-ABOVE  # remove those not in use
[sudo] password for hannu: 
...
```

For each kernel you remove you will be freeing space.

*Note that:* `linux-image` (above) will limit the purge-able list to only kernels, change `image` to `(image|headers|modules)` and you will also see related packages
where the ones with **FULLY MATCHING VERSION** (to an image to be purged) also can be purged.

The last might actually happen by a simple:

```
$ sudo apt autoremove
[sudo] password for hannu:           
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
...
... upgraded, ... newly installed, ... to remove and ... not upgraded.

$
```