I need more space in boot
I have linux ubuntu 22.04. I want to update linux but /boot partititon is full. I would like to get some space free. I have already done kernel parititions and inftrams and apt autoremove or apt autoclean but i can't get more space. Is there a solution I haven't tried or do I have to reinstall linux? Some info is in spanish.
all of the disc space is for ubuntu, i dont have other systems. ihave almost 500 mb for boot. i have that space and dont have separated as one friend reccommended so
i have seen other post but i cant fix it as ive done all, incuding unistalling “uninstall” kernels. that is the reason why i posted this
Here's some information:
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
Release: 22.04
Codename: jammy

$ uname -r
6.5.0-45-generic

$ ls /boot
config-5.15.0-117-generic memtest86+.bin
config-5.15.0-119-generic memtest86+.elf
config-5.19.0-46-generic memtest86+_multiboot.bin
config-6.2.0-37-generic System.map-5.15.0-117-generic
config-6.5.0-44-generic System.map-5.15.0-119-generic
config-6.5.0-45-generic System.map-5.19.0-46-generic
config-6.8.0-40-generic System.map-6.2.0-37-generic
efi System.map-6.5.0-44-generic
grub System.map-6.5.0-45-generic
initrd.img System.map-6.8.0-40-generic
initrd.img-5.15.0-117-generic vmlinuz
initrd.img-5.15.0-119-generic vmlinuz-5.15.0-117-generic
initrd.img-5.19.0-46-generic vmlinuz-5.15.0-119-generic
initrd.img-6.2.0-37-generic vmlinuz-5.19.0-46-generic
initrd.img-6.5.0-44-generic vmlinuz-6.2.0-37-generic
initrd.img-6.5.0-45-generic vmlinuz-6.5.0-44-generic
initrd.img.old vmlinuz-6.5.0-45-generic
lost+found vmlinuz.old

$ df
/dev/nvme0n1p5 451320 427680 0 100% /boot

$ sudo dpkg --get-selections | grep linux-image
linux-image-5.15.0-117-generic install
linux-image-5.15.0-119-generic install
linux-image-5.19.0-46-generic install
linux-image-6.2.0-37-generic install
linux-image-6.5.0-44-generic install
linux-image-6.5.0-45-generic install
linux-image-generic install
linux-image-generic-hwe-22.04 install



initramfs modified to compress = xz



$ sudo apt autoremove
Leyendo lista de paquetes... Hecho
Creando árbol de dependencias... Hecho
Leyendo la información de estado... Hecho
Tal vez quiera ejecutar «apt --fix-broken install» para corregirlo.
Los siguientes paquetes tienen dependencias incumplidas:
linux-image-generic-hwe-22.04 : Depende: linux-image-6.8.0-40-generic pero no está instalado
E: Dependencias incumplidas. Intente «apt --fix-broken install» sin paquetes (o especifique una solución).

$ sudo apt --fix-broken install
....................................
dpkg: error al procesar el archivo /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-6.8.0-40-
generic_6.8.0-40.40~22.04.3_amd64.deb (--unpack):
no se pudieron copiar los datos extraídos de './boot/vmlinuz-6.8.0-40-generic'
a '/boot/vmlinuz-6.8.0-40-generic.dpkg-new': fallo al escribir (No queda espacio
en el dispositivo)
No se escribió un informe «apport» porque el mensaje de error indica que el erro
r es de disco lleno
dpkg-deb: error: el subproceso copiado fue terminado por la s
eñal (Tubería rota)
Se encontraron errores al procesar:
/var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-6.8.0-40-generic_6.8.0-40.40~22.04.3_amd64.
deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)



$ LC_ALL=C sudo apt --fix-broken install

[sudo] password for celia: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-5.15.0-117 linux-image-5.15.0-117-generic
  linux-modules-5.15.0-117-generic linux-modules-extra-5.15.0-117-generic
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  linux-image-6.8.0-40-generic
Suggested packages:
  fdutils linux-hwe-6.8-tools
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  linux-image-6.8.0-40-generic
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 109 not upgraded.
19 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/14.7 MB of archives.
After this operation, 15.0 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 472124 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../linux-image-6.8.0-40-generic_6.8.0-40.40~22.04.3_amd64.d
eb ...
Unpacking linux-image-6.8.0-40-generic (6.8.0-40.40~22.04.3) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-6.8.0-40-gene
ric_6.8.0-40.40~22.04.3_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 cannot copy extracted data for './boot/vmlinuz-6.8.0-40-generic' to '/boot/vmli
nuz-6.8.0-40-generic.dpkg-new': failed to write (No space left on device)
No apport report written because the error message indicates a disk full error
                                                                              dp
kg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-6.8.0-40-generic_6.8.0-40.40~22.04.3_amd64.
deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)




Can not tell from the info provided so please clarify. What is the total size of the disk space you gave to Ubuntu when you first installed it? Why do you have boot as a separate partition?

https://askubuntu.com/a/1458777/289138

You can get the info in English by running LC_ALL=C sudo apt --fix-broken install. Please do that since that is where the only relevant error message is. You can simply delete some older kernels though.

If you can't remove old kernels using apt, then see https://askubuntu.com/questions/171209/my-boot-partition-hit-100-and-now-i-cant-upgrade-cant-remove-old-kernels-to

i can uninstall kernels but all of them tell me to be installed (sudo dpkg --get-selections | grep linux-image) and im afraid of doing something wrong that cracks my pc
